# Java - delete an ImageIcon?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

Is there any way to easily delete an ImageIcon completely from the screen? I can't find one anywhere.

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("candle.gif");
image.paintIcon(this, g, 150, 80)
```

For example, if I wanted to get rid of "image" later on when a button is pressed, what would be the appropriate code? (Not for the button, I know how to do that).

Comment: *select it , press delete key , hit enter*, Please make your question clear

Comment: As Jigar says, your question is very unclear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 5):

Don't reinvent the wheel. The easiest way to paint an Icon is to use a JLabel. The code would be something like:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(...);
JLabel label = new JLabel( icon );
panel.add( label );
```

If you don't want to display the icon anymore then in the ActionListener of your button you simple do:

```
label.setIcon( null );
```

Comment: When I try this, the label is always behind the other components, no matter when I add it to the pane.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. I'm not a mind reader. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.