# How to delete a image icon in java?

Tags: java, image, variables, if-statement

Hello I am trying to delete a imageicon named tree in my java game and am finding trouble with my if statements. How would I remove the image tree if the boolean drawimage equals false?

```
    if(r1.intersects(rectX, rectY, 25, 25)){
        g.drawString("Cut Down Some Tree's To Get Some Wood To build Your Base", rectX, rectX);
    drawimage = true;
    }

    if(drawimage){
        g.drawImage(tree,175, 75, 50, 50,null);


    //Check if the image has cloision
    if(r1.intersects(175, 75, 50, 50)){
    drawimage = false;
    }

    if(!drawimage){

    }
    }




repaint();
}
```

Comment: first of all, correct your last if. It should be if (drawimage==false)

Comment: where you set this image ???

Comment: Is your attempt not actually working?

Comment: How is `g` defined?  From the looks of it, you've either used `getGraphics` or are maintaining a reference to it out side the paint cycle...that or you are calling repaint from within a `paintXxx` method, in any case, it's all bad ideas

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am using Graphics g in the parameters of a object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct your code 
`if(drawimage = false){    }`

to `if(drawimage == false){    }` or

```
if(!drawimage){    }
```

Comment: By the way when i run the program and drag my mouse in the cordinates 175, 75, 50, 50 it will not set the boolean variable drawimage to false. What would I enter in the if statement if(!drawimage) to get rid of the picture tree? I have correctly defined the image tree and the file path is correct (because i see it on the screen) but what line of code would get rid of tree.

Comment: Some People are complaining that I defined the image path wrong and blah blah but here is all of my code HELP. How can I delete the imageicon tree??!!!

Comment: see this link if useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914608/java-delete-an-imageicon

Comment: Omg Thank you So Much I Am Soooooo Grateful :)!